# VBA, string arguments in UDF that does not have quotation marks - how to access their value?

Tags: vba, arguments, user-defined-functions, quotation-marks

My function in a VBA is:

```
Function myFunc(a)
    myFunc = a    
End Function
```

When I use this function in Excel sheet in this way `=myFunc("abc")`, it is working, but when I use formula without pair of quotating marks `=myFunc(abc)`, then I'm receiving error `#NAME?`.

Trying change argument from `Function myFunc(a)` to `Function myFunc(chr(34) & a & chr (34) )` leads to error `Expected: )`.

How can I access a value that was typed without quotation marks in a UDF ( user defined function )?

Update: I need it to simplify usage of UDF for end user.

Comment: I am quite sure you can't unless it is for examle a defined name in the sheet where you use the UDF. And I am also quite sure you can't use a text without quotation marks in a "standard" UDF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why do you need something like that. **But it is possible**! Read about Application.Caller - it's rng where UDF is running.

```
 Private Function myFuncCalc(ByVal xstr As String)
 ' it is your main function to calculate what you want
 ' just sample code to test below
   If xstr = "USD" Then
    myFuncCalc = "yes it's american dollar!"
   Else
    myFuncCalc = "it's no american dollar"
   End If
 End Function

 Function myFunc(a)
 ' function just to be available in worksheet
 ' and extracting currency letter codes from formula between brackets
   bra1 = InStr(Application.Caller.Formula, "(")
   bra2 = InStr(Application.Caller.Formula, ")")
   x = Mid(Application.Caller.Formula, bra1 + 1, bra2 - bra1 - 1)
   myFunc = myFuncCalc(x)
 End Function
```

Voila!

Answer (score 1):

If you use it without quotes, excel is expecting a named range. If what you want is to get the contents from another cell, you should define the argument as `myfunction(a as Range)` and then get its value using `a.Value2` or `a.Text`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I'm writing a function, in which user can write a name of currency, than my function will ask via API rate from a bank site and after all function will return rate. I'd like that userside of my function will be in a such way: `=myFunc(CAD)`, not `=myFunc("CAD")`. If I write a name of a currence in a separate cell, than it will work: `=myFunc(A1)`

Comment: Are you not listening? That's what Sama and I are writing. If it is a named range then it's okay and A1 is the name for the cell in row 1 and column 1. But you can't write `func(CAD)` because Excel cannot interpret `CAD` as a string. Try to use `Find` in the same way as you want to use your UDF. I am afraid but what you want it is just not possible.

Comment: Dear @Storax, please, do not agry on me - new answer from Rafał B. showed, that it IS possible. Unfortunatly, I do not have enough reputation, to vote Rafal's answer.Can you, please, vote  his answer?

Comment: Why should I be angry? If you need something like that and Rafal implemented it, go ahead. I did not think of it. @Rafal B.: Very good but as you wrote _I also don't know why one would need something like that_